# Is there a way to group emails by sender or receipient in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, metadata

We get a lot of vendors where I work, and frequently it becomes necessary to find an old vendor by what they fixed before successfully.

To identify "this person was good at X, lets request that person again".

In this way it would be helpful to be able to do a `GROUP BY` in Outlook for finding these vendors again.

Can this be done by recipient and/or sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this result?

[image]

If so, we can easily choose "From" in the upper right corner of the message list. And under View tab, we can choose Expand or Collapse the groups.
[image]

Hope to help you!

Comment: "Groups" just change the order in which emails are listed. So what does it mean to "Expand or Collapse" the groups?"